Batch command with quotes fails to move files and delete folder with special characters
I have a custom batch program that I update and run to negate having to constantly waste half an hour just to clean up the Windows start menu every time I'm forced to reinstall Windows. It saves me a lot of hassle and I've got it pretty refined except there is one thing refusing to work.
Unlike literally every other shortcut (*.lnk) and directory, this does not work:
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\AMD Software꞉ Adrenalin Edition"
move "AMD Software꞉ Adrenalin Edition.lnk" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System\Settings"
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
rmdir /S /Q "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\AMD Software꞉ Adrenalin Edition"

I know that the : character has special meaning and that is why the NTFS file system doesn't allow it's use. So whoever was in charge of the installer felt very compelled to use a similar character: modifier letter colon (U+A789).
How do I modify my batch program to move the file and delete the parent directory?

Have you tried removing any attributes and/or replacing ":" with "?"  rmdir /s /q "C:\ ... \AMD Software? Adrenalin Edition"?

@Io-oI Using ? in place of the modifier letter color moved the file though it did not rename the file or delete the directory. What is that bit about attributes?

see, non-actions point to attribute constraints (just guessing)

The name you are seeing is probably not the real name of the file, use:
 dir /a /x

To see the file's real name and delete it, if the real name has really a colon in it try deleting by using the shortname (8.3).
